# Immediate stroke/seizure Therapy

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

Can an oncoming stroke/seizure, be stopped by a setup consisting of a brain-computer-interface (BCI) that immediately detects the variation in wave-form, and then another machine that neutralizes the anomaly by sending a measured voltage to select areas of the brain OR by Transcranial Magnetic Stimulation?

Comment: Can you please use names (not initialisms)? What is a BCI? Also, stroke and seizure are two completely different entities. You can't stop a stroke with electricity or transcranial magnetic stimulation.

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE. Nice qunction - I think the seizure part is an interesting thought. However, how a stroke could be detected by its electrical signature, or how it could be prevented by electrical stimuli seems a bit out of context here, and hardly possible for that matter. Perhaps consider focusing on seizures to give the question focus.

Comment: @anongoodnurse (I hope you get a ping - I am mobile) - when giving it a second thought - if it would be possible to transfer a large current and coagulate the impeding rupturing vessel, one could, theoretically, use currents to prevent a stroke? But again, predicting it by electrical recordings seems impossible.

Comment: To give a jolt strong enough to coagulate blood in a vessel might do more harm than good... and then there are ischemic strokes (>80%).

Comment: @anongoodnurse - I see, practically it clearly doesn't make sense - thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these devices and treatment programs are being actively developed. General idea is that epileptic episode follows certain path within the brain. It can start in thalamus, after which sporadic activity spreads into cortical areas, for example motor cortex. There is a number of papers on prediction of epileptic seizure, e.g. [Seizure Prediction and its Applications](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3237404/).

The device then will detect initiation of seizure before evident symptoms and provide inhibition via cortical electrodes, microelectrode array (MEA). It seems that currently MEAs are used more for research ([recording from tens of neurons](http://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/news/publications/neuronow/neuronow_spring_2012/for_epilepsy_a_microelectrode_array_with_big_promise)), but single electrodes are useful for actual control of epilepsy. Also one can control vagus nerve, which causes parasympathetic response (general inhibition, aka "rest-and-digest"). More you can read [here](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/epilepsy/diagnosis-treatment/treatment/txc-20117241).

Transcranial magnetic stimulation, as I understand, is not portable enough to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a long comment than an answer:

There have been active research in this area for several decades now. The problem is that once you detect seizure (which is relatively easy), it's usually too late. Therefore, a lot of effort has been to **predict** epileptic seizures some time before it happens. This has proven quite difficult.

See this review article for the state-of-the-art in 2007:

- Mormann, F., Andrzejak, R. G., Elger, C. E., and Lehnertz, K. (2007). Seizure prediction: the long and winding road. Brain, 130(2):314-333.
  http://ntsa.upf.edu/system/files/biblio/Mormann-Brain2007.pdf